# Managing .zip and file in python

Tags: python, zip, unzip

So I'm Downloading the PyOpenGL module. But on the page, it says that it needs Togl widget for OpenGL to be used with Tkinter. So I came on this site :https://sourceforge.net/projects/togl/ and download the file. But it gave me a .zip file and when I unzip it, there's just a bunch of files group together with the filename 'Togl'. Where should I put this file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That site has a link to docs, which include a chapter on [Download/Install](http://togl.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Comment: However, I notice that it's over a decade since the last update. No promises that it will build with modern versions of Python, OpenGL, platform libraries, and Tcl/Tk…

Comment: PyOpenGL seems almost as dead; it's made for Python 3.3 and 2.7 only, and with "experimental" support for OpenGL 4.4, which is two versions out of date.

Comment: @abarnert But I'm kind of desperate to get at least something to create a 3D object, could you recommend anything that I could use in python Tkinter? Cause I don't want to build it from scratch with all that matrix and vector and stuff...